# AWS SES sender address verification notification

Tags: amazon-web-services, sdk, amazon-ses

Is there currently any way to receive notification that a specific user has verified their address (clicked the link on the verification e-mail)? My app allows users to send messages via SES. I can successfully generate the verification message for the user, but short of polling AWS SES to see if user X is verified I'm unable to determine if a user has verified.

I suppress email functionality until addresses are verified, and would love to be notified when this event happens.

Comment: Not possible. Either AWS console or http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/APIReference/API_ListVerifiedEmailAddresses.html

Comment: SES services are sandboxed and you need to verify from and to both email address. Also you are limited to 200 emails per 24hrs. You can raise a support ticket to get out of Sandbox and then you dont need to verify the to addresses.